# What is the difference between Modular Arithmetic and Modulo Operation ?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, distribution-of-primes

Trying to rub the dust from my math knowledge, I am trying to understand, or perhaps recall, the Modular Arithmetic and Modulo Operation but I kinda can't get what the differences are between these two is ? 
From Wikipedia :

> This section is about the (mod n) notation. For the binary mod
>   operation, see modulo operation.

[The link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Definition_of_congruence_relation)

Answer (score 4):

The modulo operation (I will use $\%$ for that here) is an *operation*, like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. It is something you do to two numbers to get a result. For instance, $12\mathbin\%10 = 2$.

Modular arithmetic uses a *relation*, like equals, less-than and divides. It is something you do to *compare* two numbers. For instance, $12\equiv 2\pmod{10}$. Note that $\pmod{10}$ here is part of the $\equiv$. It might be clearer if we write something like $12\equiv_{10}2$, although that's not standard notation.

Arithmetic modulo $10$ means, somewhat simplified, "Use ${}\mathbin\%10$ on everything, all the time, before you compare them with $=$."

Comment: One difference is that you can write $72\equiv 42  \pmod{10}$ but not $72\mathbin\%10 = 42$ nor `mod(72,10)=42`

Comment: @Henry Although you _do_ have $72\mathbin\%10 = 42\mathbin\%10$. In fact, one might take this as the _definition_ of $\equiv_{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Modular arithmetic is a different kind of arithmetic where your operation is a modulo operation. When you look at the clockface you count modulo $12$. When we count the weeks of a year we count modulo $52$. Modular arithmetic utilizes this "wrapping around" idea, after you reached the greatest element comes the smallest. So modular arithmetic is a sort of a mindset.

A binary operation is an operation which combines two elements, for example addition is a binary operation since it combines two elements. Even when you add three things together you always do it by twos, that is
$$
3+4+5=7+5=12
$$
you always operate only on two numbers.

So to recap $(\bmod n)$ means that whenever you operate on elements so you will set the $n$th element equal to the first. And a binary modulo operation is the operation itself you use.

Hope this helps.